# Numpy gradient() with OpenCV is never negative

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I've been playing around with OpenCV and Numpy and I just noticed that when taking the gradient of a grayscale image, it is never negative. I haven't tried it with colour. Why is this happening?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = video_capture.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

Gx,Gy = np.gradient(gray)
print "Gradient X"
print Gx[Gx<0]
print "\n\nGradient Y"
print Gy[Gy<0]

test_gx,test_gy = np.gradient(np.random.rand(10,10))
print "\n\nRandom Gradient X"
print test_gx[test_gx<0]
print "\n\nRandom Gradient Y"
print test_gy[test_gy<0]
```

Output:

```
Gradient X
[]


Gradient Y
[]


Random Gradient X
[-0.29390267 -0.57673461 -0.44496392 -0.18760622 -0.37758506 -0.02940484
 -0.09905821 -0.12909104 -0.22726427 -0.17175216 -0.08635539 -0.02969735
 -0.05939525 -0.02111877 -0.29544231 -0.00770492 -0.31914318 -0.12239945
 -0.30133711 -0.08622408 -0.04524624 -0.03998993 -0.40993412 -0.13088891
 -0.2491598  -0.14143661 -0.04846196 -0.30055182 -0.00323793 -0.49329475
 -0.07413882 -0.17564328 -0.13582564 -0.13390455 -0.07373904 -0.09886662
 -0.08773134 -0.06185525 -0.00729722 -0.18979578 -0.17536514 -0.25615883
 -0.26232646 -0.05403582 -0.05968006 -0.26843946 -0.26621363 -0.22504563
 -0.26470668 -0.02397445 -0.0782202  -0.0476783  -0.13333021]


Random Gradient Y
[-0.29521569 -0.23485359 -0.15549854 -0.00142858 -0.07242038 -0.32181099
 -0.26111095 -0.10534067 -0.20442231 -0.05366269 -0.01339253 -0.01597691
 -0.10289234 -0.14128584 -0.1705936  -0.14574768 -0.17571418 -0.04868263
 -0.46254485 -0.11305848 -0.208527   -0.03967778 -0.06671698 -0.35017431
 -0.68122837 -0.37782762 -0.30486289 -0.23501836 -0.25857174 -0.33494929
 -0.27348378 -0.319753   -0.06541161 -0.29203723 -0.1875851  -0.07090711
 -0.07814288 -0.20096383 -0.31743231 -0.17801282 -0.02341537 -0.11358367
 -0.3985152  -0.07670008 -0.02248808 -0.35775219 -0.28470273]
```

Comment: Is your image blank (i.e. one color) causing the gradient to be 0 everywhere

Comment: Nope, it's a grayscale webcam image.

Comment: Ben can you show us the exact image contained in `gray`?

Comment: The image I was testing it on in my actual code was this, converted to grayscale: http://media.tumblr.com/42e9e2a366fc2f051e257e989450a069/tumblr_inline_mrmig7OZPE1qz4rgp.jpg

Comment: The exact image is a live grayscale image from my webcam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the image from the camera in an unsigned integer, so it cannot have negative values.
Try doing this instead:

```
Gx,Gy = np.gradient(gray.astype('float32'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate a bit on yhenon’s answer : obviously the gradient of an unsigned integer array **may have** negative values.  The point is that `np.gradient(myarray)` is of the same type as `myarray`, so it will force negative values to high positive values :

```
>>> myarray = np.array([1,3,5,7,8,6,4,2], dtype='uint8')
>>> np.gradient(myarray)
array([   2. ,    2. ,    2. ,    1.5,  127.5,  126. ,  126. ,  254. ])
```

Such behaviour is a bug, which has actually [been reported as such](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/15207) and in principle [fixed in numpy 1.18.1](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/release/1.18.1-notes.html).

The workaround for earlier versions is indeed to cast the input into a signed integer type is just to allow negative values for the gradient itself :

```
>>> np.gradient(myarray.astype('int16'))
array([ 2. ,  2. ,  2. ,  1.5, -0.5, -2. , -2. , -2. ])
```

**Beware** that in order to handle correctly large variations one should cast to a twice larger type at least — i.e. `uint8` to `int16`, `uint32` to `int64`, etc.  For the `numpy` bugfix they chose to convert to `float64`.